# Display elements of json array using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

Being a novice to angularjs framework I'm attempting to use a controller to retrieve a JSON and display elements,but the desired result is not displayed.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../public/javascripts/processJson.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
   <div ng-app="getJson"><div ng-controller="controller1">
      <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
       <div ng-switch-when="text"><input type="text" id="{{post.id}}" ng-model="post.value" placeholder="{{post.placeholder}}">
 </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Controller :** **processJson.js**

```
 var getJson = angular.module('getJson', []).controller('controller1',   function ($scope, $http) {
var url = "../../routes/fields.js";
console.log(url);
$http.get(url).success(function (data) {
    $scope.posts = data;
  });

 });
```

**fields.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var router =express.Router();


 router.get('/fieldlist',function(req,res){
  var db=req.db;
  var collection=db.get('domlist');
   collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.json(docs); 
  });  
});

module.exports=router;
```

Also utilising mongodb to store and retrieve as JSON data.. URL http://localhost:3000/fields/fieldlist  returns my  json array stored in mongodb.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what the JSON looks like please?

Comment: Please include where you facing problem? Do you get desired data in $scope.posts?

Comment: @PhilKearney  added more code

Comment: @Navaneeth added more code

Answer (score 2):

Can you try `$scope.posts = data.data`.

The HTTP request will return an object with the data property inside:

> The response object has these properties:
>
> data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
>   transform functions. status – {number} – HTTP status code of the
>   response. headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
>   config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate
>   the request. statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

For more information: [API Reference - $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 1):

You have a ng-switch-when without an ng-switch around that causes me an error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngSwitch', required by directive 'ngSwitchWhen', can't be found!
```

I've prepared a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ab19ozh/